# C# Datatable filtered data to --> Livechart(piechart)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, c#-4.0, charts

Please look at the image first. What I want to do is: To transfer the filtered data in the table numerically according to the pie chart. Please read the codes .I want to export the data in the "GelirMiktari" column to the pie chart. Why does it all write 25%.
I want the pie chart to be shaped according to the data in the "GiderMiktari" column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn1Tn.jpg)

```
private void btn_gider_bilgi_getir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string veritabaniyolu = "Data source=veritabani.db";
            string ay = cbox_g_gun.Text;
            string yil = cbox_g_yil.Text;
            bunifuDataGridView1.DataSource = null;

            SQLiteConnection baglanti = new SQLiteConnection(veritabaniyolu);
            baglanti.Open();
            string sql_tarih_sorgula = $"SELECT * FROM Gelirler WHERE GelirTarihi BETWEEN '{yil}-{ay}-01' AND '{yil}-{ay}-31'";
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql_tarih_sorgula, baglanti);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            bunifuDataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            baglanti.Close();

                Func<ChartPoint, string> labelPoint = chartPoint => string.Format("{0} ({1:P})", chartPoint.Y, chartPoint.Participation);
                SeriesCollection piechartData = new SeriesCollection();
                var collection = bunifuDataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().GroupBy(x => x.Cells[1].Value).Where(g => g.Count() > 0).Select(y => new { Element = y.Key, Counter = y.Count() }).ToList();
                foreach (var item in collection)
                {
                    piechartData.Add(new PieSeries { Title = Convert.ToString(item.Element), Values = new ChartValues<int> { (int)item.Counter }, DataLabels = true, LabelPoint = labelPoint });
    
                }
    
                pieChart1.Series = piechartData;
                pieChart1.LegendLocation = LegendLocation.Right;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code to create a pie chart for filtering the number column based on the datetime column.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite");
            m_dbConnection.Open();
            string sql = string.Format("Select * From example where Birthdate between '{0}-{1}-01' AND '{0}-{1}-31'", textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text);
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, m_dbConnection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            m_dbConnection.Close();
            Func<ChartPoint, string> labelPoint = chartPoint => string.Format("{0} ({1:P})", chartPoint.Y, chartPoint.Participation);
            // Define a collection of items to display in the chart 
            SeriesCollection piechartData = new SeriesCollection();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                piechartData.Add(new PieSeries { Title = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Cells["Birthdate"].Value).ToShortDateString(), Values = new ChartValues<double> {Convert.ToDouble(item.Cells["Number"].Value)}, DataLabels = true, LabelPoint = labelPoint });
            }
            pieChart1.Series = piechartData;
            // Set the legend location to appear in the Right side of the chart
            pieChart1.LegendLocation = LegendLocation.Right;
        }
```

Result:

[image]